# Why is it that the angle around any arbitrary closed curve is 2 pi?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to motivate the idea of a solid angle and so I decided to relate it to the regular angle.  And I realized I'm a little hazy on that as well.

Why is it that the angle around any arbitrary closed curve is $2\pi$?  For a circle, we can relate the angle to the arc length via $s = \theta r$, then $\theta = \frac sr$.  Because $s$ depend linearly on $r$, $\theta$ is really independent of radius.  This seems to be the reason why we can measure angles arbitrary closed curves, but it would imply that $s=\theta r$ holds for non-circles as well.  I don't see any justification for that.

Maybe I just don't have a good enough definition of "angle".  So what is the definition?  And why is the angle around any arbitrary closed curve $2\pi$?

Comment: Because you can always deform your arbitrary closed curve into a circle - like straightening out a rubber band.

Comment: I don't understand well what you mean by the angle "around" a closed curve. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Is this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117636/ a response to your question?